# How to programmatically open PrimeFaces-Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I know there are plenty of questions about this topic, but none could help me.

I just want to open a dialog via my managed bean because I need a plain object to work on, so I wanted an actionListener, which produces a new object and then opens the dialog.

Problem: It does not work. Why? I do not know.

I do not get any error in any console. No JS-errors, nothing in my Tomcat-Console, nothing in his logs. And I am very, very sure it should work this way.

Here is what I made:

The "add"-Button:

```
<p:outputPanel style="float:right">
<p:commandButton value="Hinzufügen" icon="ui-icon-plusthick"
    actionListener="#{lessonTypeController.addLessonTypeDialog}" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

The actionListener looks as follows:

```
public void addLessonTypeDialog() {

    lessonType = new LessonType();
    lessonType.setTypicalDuration(getTypicalDuration());
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("PF('addLessonTypeDialog').show()");

}
```

And the dialog that should be opened (but does not want to):

```
<p:dialog header="Add a lessontype"
    id="addLessonTypeDialog" widgetVar="addLessonTypeDialog"
    minHeight="600" modal="true" draggable="false" resizable="false">
    <p:ajax event="close" update="@form" />
    <p:outputPanel>
        ... Some content which works fine if dialog is called different
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

The dialog is placed in the same xhtml-page as the calling button.

I really don't know why this does not work. As I said I am really, really sure it is correct this way. Also no errors. Just not a single reaction when I click the button.

Everything else works fine, I also use dialogs which are in own xhtml-pages, which works fine, but has to be refactored now, because I need the close-event to update the form.

If I call the dialog directly via JS (like I did in the bean, just with an onlick-event for the button) it works, but I get problems because the actionListener is not fast enough to produce a new object before the JS has already shown the dialog what results in errors and NullPointerExceptions.

Please help me, this is for an important project in school I have to finish alone due to my mates doing nothing and I really don't know what to do.

Comment: is stackoverflow project completing site ?

Comment: I did not know that it matters where a programming-problem occurs. If it makes you happy I invest a lot of free time in it.

Comment: chk this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152789/create-primefaces-dialogs-dynamically#answer-12638195

Comment: two suggestions: First: update the dialog in the commandButton (`update="dialogId"`). Sec: add appendToBody="true" in `<p:dialog>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that in some previous versions strange things happened when you have `widgetVar` with the same value as `id`. So, try to change one of them and see if it works:

```
context.execute("PF('wAddLessonTypeDialog').show()");

<p:dialog id="addLessonTypeDialog" widgetVar="wAddLessonTypeDialog" ...
```

To quote the author of Primefaces, from [this thread](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18830)

> Don't give component id and widgetVar same name.

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your reply. I actually had it this way in the first place but then went on some try and error and made it both the same. I changed it the way you suggested and tried to call it via the ID and via the widgetVar (the widgetVar is used, right?), but it did not change a thing.

Comment: Yes, widgetVar is used. Is `actionListener` getting executed at all?

Comment: It... isn't. That does not make any sense, I have more of these pages with more of these buttons and they are calling their listeners. I will debug that now, thanks for the heads up. I still have no clue what's wrong.

Comment: Try putting `process="@this"` on the button, and see if that helps.

Comment: YES! Oh god, it helped. Thank you! Really.
Would you mind to explain why I need that in this setup? The other buttons work fine without it.

Comment: To be honest, I'm confused also because `@this` should be the default if you don't specify anything else. Anyway, it proved to be a valuable debugging technique for Primefaces :)

Answer (score 0):

What about configuration? Try [checking that your faces-config contains the Dialog Framework Configuration (Page 519 in the Primefaces 5.1 Users Guid, it's easy to miss):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537499/cant-get-primefaces-requestcontext-getcurrentinstance-opendialog-to-work).

```
<application>
  <action-listener>
    org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener
  </action-listener>
  <navigation-handler>
    org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler
  </navigation-handler>
  <view-handler>
    org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler
  </view-handler>
</application>
```

Comment: I just saw your answer. My faces-config does NOT contain any of this, the problem was already solved and it works just fine without it.